# How to create an action replay of what the user does on the screen?

Tags: ios

I need to write an app which will allow the user to replay what they have just done; to play back all their actions. Is it possible to record what happens on the screen in some form of video file?

Answer (score 0):

Capturing all the UI Actions in NScoding objects to later recreating, animating and saving them in a video format could be an option! 
Redo Undo actions seems good to start!